# Unable to Call Method in Another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods, message

I am using forward declaration in the calling Class.

**.h file** in ClassTwo

```
@class ClassOne

@property(nonatomic,retain) ClassOne *class_One;
```

**.m file**

```
@synthesize class_One;
```

Then i am trying to call this method in ClassOne

```
[self.class_One callingThisMethodFromClassTwo];
```

On the other hand if i create a shared instance in ClassOne and use it as a class method it works

```
[[ClassOne Shared] nowItWorks];
```

Sorry if this is a silly question i am very new

Comment: Is the method you're calling a class method? When you declare a method, the + before it (+(void)classMethod:(id)sender) means it's a class method, and would only be able to be called by [ClassOne classMethod:self];, and a - before it (-(void)instanceMethod:(id)sender) denotes an instance method, meaning it would be called by ClassOne *classOne = [[ClassOne alloc]init]; [classOne instanceMethod:self];

Comment: Did you allocated or set that variable ?

Comment: Are you importing `ClassOne.h` in the second case perhaps? Importing it at the top of your ClassTwo.m should make the first version work too.

Comment: @Echihl: The method i am calling is an instance method it starts like this -(void)thisIsTheMethod. When a create a class method +(void)Shared then i can the instance like this [[ClassOne Shared]thisIsTheMethod]. Hope i make sense

Comment: At **the top of your .m file** you need to add **#import "ClassOne.h"**. If you forgot to import the header the compiler only knows the defined placeholder class, which doesn't have any methods! But this should be described in the compiler warning anyway.

Comment: @miho: Yes it is imported already

Comment: Why "@class ClassOne" instead of "@class ClassTwo" ?

Comment: What kind of issue does `[self.class_One callingThisMethodFromClassTwo];` produce? A compiler error/warning, an exception on runtime or just nothing happens?

Comment: If just nothing happens you may have forgotten to allocate and init the class_One var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to allocate class_One instance and add `#import "ClassOne.h"` to headers on top of your  `classtwo.m`

```
self.class_One= [[ClassOne alloc]init]; 
[self.class_One callingThisMethodFromClassTwo];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `[self.class_One callingThisMethodFromClassTwo];` fails... this directly refers that

1. Either class_One is not alloc+init-ed.
2. Or `callingThisMethodFromClassTwo` is a private/protected method.
3. Or `callingThisMethodFromClassTwo` is a class method.

Answer (score 0):

I am recommending you to use `Protocol/Delegate` for this issue.

You Should declare a delegate protocol for your class. An example of a delegate protocol and interface for class Foo might be in this way:

@protocol MyClassDelegate

// Required means if they want to use the delegate they
// have to implement it.
@required
   // method that you want to call from another class.
- (void)taskComplete:(BOOL)complete;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    // We don't know what kind of class is going to adopt us at
    //compile time, that's why this is an id
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

- (void)taskComplete;
- (void)doSomeTask;

Suppose you have a complex project and don’t want to create lots of 
 linkages between your classes, in that case delegation like this is going to be your best way to implement. It’s like having function pointers ad callbacks, but the communication goes both ways easily. Time to adopt our protocol and actually use it in a class.

```
myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
// Very important. If we don't let myClass know who the delegate
// is we'll never get the protocol methods called to us.
[myClass setDelegate:self];
```

In this you can call method from another class. I hope this will help you.